# How does this equality work

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

In this book I have the equality
F(x) = F($\bar{x}$) + $\int^{1}_{0}\frac{\partial F(\bar{x}+t(x-\bar{x})}{\partial t}$

Then this is equal to (and I’m unclear why it’s by the chain rule)

F($\bar{x}$) + $\int^{1}_{0}\nabla F(\bar{x}+t(x-\bar{x}))^T (x-\bar{x}) dt$

Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $x$ and $\bar x$ and define $g(t):=F(\bar{x}+t(x-\bar{x}))$ for $t \in [0,1].$ Then

$$\int^{1}_{0}\frac{\partial F(\bar{x}+t(x-\bar{x}))}{\partial t} =\int^{1}_{0}g'(t) dt=g(1)-g(0)=F(x)-F( \bar x).$$

Comment: Can you explain how we get the next part? I don’t see the relationship between a partial derivative and a gradient without a dot product

Answer (score 0):

To answer your other question about

> $$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial t} F(\bar x + t(x - \bar x)) = \nabla F(\bar x + t(x - \bar x))^T(x - \bar x)$$

try to think about what the left-hand side is expressing. As $t$ varies, $\bar x + t(x-\bar x)$ traverses the line between $\bar x$ and $x$. We can evaluate $F$ along that line, and we want to know the derivative of that function of $t$.

But as $t$ varies, every coordinate of $\bar x + t(x - \bar x)$ changes, and each one of those coordinates is an input to $F$. So to find the derivative of $F$ along the line, we need to combine the partial derivatives of $F$ with respect to each of these coordinates, with the derivatives of these coordinates with respect to $t$. That's the chain rule.

With a bit more explicit notation, let $x = (x_1,\dots, x_n)$ and $\bar x = (\bar x_1,\dots,\bar x_n)$. Then
$$\begin{aligned}
    \frac{\partial F}{\partial t} F(\bar x + t(x - \bar x))
    &= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i} F(\bar x + t(x - \bar x))
        \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\bar x_i + t(x_i - \bar x_i))
    \\&= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i} F(\bar x + t(x - \bar x))(x_i - \bar x_i)
    \\&=  \nabla F(\bar x + t(x - \bar x))^T(x - \bar x)
\end{aligned}$$

It is a common abuse of notation to let $x_i$ be the name of one of the input variables of $F$, and also one of the output variables of $t \mapsto \bar x + t(x-\bar x)$. That can complicate fully understanding the formula.